# Growth rate of cohomology

Tags: ct.category-theory, linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Fix a finite dimensional graded vector space $V$, a differential $d$ on $V \otimes V $ $(i.e.\,\, d^2=0\,\, and \,\, deg\, d =1)$ such that $(d_{1,2} \otimes id_3)$ anti-commutes with $((-1)^{deg}_1 \otimes d_{2,3}) $ on $V \otimes V \otimes V$. Define $V_N$ to be cohomology of $(d_{1,2}+d_{2,3}+d_{3,4}+...+d_{n-1,n})$ on $V^{\otimes n}$. Here $d_{i,i+1}$ means $d$ acting on i-th and (i+1)-th factor (and it’s (-1)^{deg} on factors before i and id on factors after (i +1) ) . Can we prove that $dim\, (V_N)\sim Ca^NN^b $for some algebraic number a and integer b?  (Actually I guess it’s a combination of polynomials and exponentials)

Comment: How do you build a complex from $V\otimes V$? How do you define $d_{i,j}$?

Comment: The underlying space of the complex (if there is a compatible grading) is $V^{\otimes n}$, where $d_{ij}$ means $d$ acting on i-th and j-th factor (and it’s id on other factors)

Comment: Are you sure this is a differential? If $n=4$ I get $(d_{1,2}+d_{2,3} + d_{3,4} + d_{4,1} )^2 = d_{1,2}d_{3,4} + d_{3,4} d_{1,2} + d_{2,3}d_{4,1}+ d_{4,1} d_{2,3}= 2 d_{1,2}d_{3,4} + 2 d_{2,3} d_{4,1}$ which seems nonzero.

Comment: Oh sorry this is my mistake, I really want V to be graded and impose Koszul sign rule so that $d_{12}$ anticommutes with $d_{34}$. I will correct the question

Comment: Many thanks for point this out!

Comment: @WillSawin: dose this make more sense now? In fact I feel I may or may not add the last $d_{n1}$ they should be have similar behavior.

Comment: Yes, I agree that this works. I'm concerned if you add the last factor then the commutation relation may stop working because "before" and "after" start behaving strangely. I checked by hand the case $\dim V= 2$ and I have some insight into the structure of possible $d$ but so far don't see how to turn that structure into a description of the cohomology.

Comment: If $d$ satisfies the anti-commutation relation you consider there are algebras $A$ and $B$ inside $\operatorname{End} (V)$ which are sums of their graded pieces and $d$ has the form $ (-1)^{ \operatorname{deg}_1} (\sum_i a_i \otimes b_i)$ for some $a_i \in A$ and $b_i \in B$, and conversely, any $d$ of this form satisfies the anti-commutation relation. I don't yet see any way to simplify this data of algebras $A$ and $B$, an $(A,B)$-bimodule $V$, and a tensor in $A \otimes B$  but that might be a good approach.

Comment: @WillSawin: yes I definitely agree with what you said, this looks really important. As to your first concern, as one rotate around 12...n for one time $d_{12}$ would become $(-1)^ {deg} d_{12}$, but intuitively this would not change the cohomology, as for a double complex $d_1\pm d_2$ have same cohomology.

Comment: Multiplying by $(-1)^{\operatorname{deg}}$ could spoil the anticommutation relation though.

Comment: @WillSawin: Yes you are right! The signs cause issue here. Thank you for correcting this.

Comment: @WillSawin: a more careful definition of $d_{n1}$ would make it work: let’s denote $T$ to be the translation with Koszul sign rule, i.e. $T(a_1\otimes a_2\otimes \cdots\otimes a_n)=(-1)^ {|a_1|(|a_2|+\cdots+|a_n|)} a_2\otimes \cdots\otimes a_n\otimes a_1$ then we have $d_{12}$ anti commutes with $d_{23}=T^{-1}d_{12}T$, we can define $d_{n1} =Td_{12}T^{-1}$ then everything is good. Does this make sense? Many thanks again!